# Converting Json to Hashmap

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I have a json string

```
{

  {

     key1:[values1]
  },

  {

     key2:[values2]
  }

}
```

I want to convert it into `HashMap(String,Object)` in java.

I have been using normal json parsing, where I create a jsonObject from the json string and extract jsonArrays from the jsonObject. Is there any direct API to convert it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use jackson for JSON manipulation.

Check this out for other useful examples: 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/

Regarding your question:

```
public class JsonMapExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "{\"name\":\"mkyong\", \"age\":29}";

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        // convert JSON string to Map
        map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});

        System.out.println(map);

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, one of my friend was telling about jackson api, but I was not able to find relevant examples. This one is close to my json format

Comment: Np. Examples are the best way to learn!

Comment: `Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Map.class)` works for me. With TypeReference, I have to override the getTypeName() method